# why past continuous in this case as both actions are completed at the time of writing

Tags: past-tense

A side is Freak Out, B side is Dr. Hoo Hoo, Mr. Tomomatsu were recording and mixing the same as the previous two 7", and legendary L.A Punk's engineer/producer GEZA X were mastering these songs.

why past continous? Is it to emphasize the lenghts of the recording and the mixing? .

I think past simple could  do it as both mixing and recording are over and completed  at the time of writing .

Comment: It depends on the rest of the context, which you have not provided.  They were doing something [while something else was going on in the paragraph or at some specific time.]

Comment: Here is the links  https://floridasdying.com/collections/full-catalog/products/geros-the-freakout-7

Comment: sorry I thought i gave it

Comment: The writing in that paragraph sounds like a punked-out fan who can't write. Past continuous does not make sense there. Simple past would be better. Cheers.